# Not able to set location model to null in contact entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring mvc app in which I have 2 model classes. Following are my model classes:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class ContactModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="contactid")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int contactId;

    @Column(name="contactname")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name="contactemail")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="contactphone")
    private String phone;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
    private LocationModel locationModel;

    public LocationModel getLocationModel() {
        return locationModel;
    }
    public void setLocationModel(LocationModel locationModel) {
        this.locationModel = locationModel;
    }
    public int getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }
    public void setContactId(int contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

and LocationModel

```
import java.util.List;

//import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

@Entity
@Table(name="Location")
public class LocationModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="locationid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private int locationId;

    @Column(name="locationname")
    private String locationName;

    @Column(name="locationdesc")
    private String locationDescription;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String locationType;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="district")
    private String district;

    @Column(name="lattitude")
    private String lattitude;

    @Column(name="longitude")
    private String longitude;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "locationModel")
    private List<ContactModel> contactList;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getLattitude() {
        return lattitude;
    }

    public void setLattitude(String lattitude) {
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLocationType() {
        return locationType;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public void setLocationType(String locationType) {
        this.locationType = locationType;
    }

    public int getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(int locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public String getLocationName() {
        return locationName;
    }

    public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }

    public String getLocationDescription() {
        return locationDescription;
    }

    public void setLocationDescription(String locationDescription) {
        this.locationDescription = locationDescription;
    }
}
```

On deleting location I want to set location of corresponding contacts to null. I am using following code for this:

```
public void selLocationToNull(int locationId) throws Exception {
        try {
            logger.info("deleteContact() begins:");
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("update ContactModel set locationModel=:newLocation where locationModel=:locationId");
            query.setParameter("newLocation", null);
            query.setParameter("locationId", locationId);
            query.executeUpdate();
            logger.info("null update query executed...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Error while updating location to null: "
                    + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

I am getting exception for this:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.bizmerlin.scm.model.LocationModel.locationId

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.bizmerlin.scm.model.LocationModel.locationId to java.lang.Integer
```

I have getter method for locationId in my LocationModel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you set a null to a primitive type? It is generally good practice to use wrapper types for fields in your Entity.

```
@Id
@Column(name="locationid")
@GeneratedValue 
private Integer locationId;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used locationModel.locationId=:locationId and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You set in the query's where LocationModel and compare it with int. SHould be

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update ContactModel set locationModel=:newLocation where locationModel.id=:locationId");
```

instead. Or pass the LocationModel instance rather than id